# C++ Qt 5.3.1 x64 Software crash on Sleep function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a c++ Qt5.3.1 software build with Visual Studio 2013 (MSVC12). I have 2 pcs with the same hardware. On 1 of the pcs the software is running fine. On this other it is crashing at startup.

I have done some debugging and it seems it is crashing on the Sleep() function !!

Any idea what I could have installed (or not installed) on 1 of the pcs that would cause this ?

(I am currently trying windows update...)

Any help would be mostly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, have you tried an empty project with only sleep() function on both of your computers ? Which sleep() function do you use ?

Comment: I did not try that. But I actually have a complete software suite which is running. And they also have Sleeps inside... This specific software is so far the only one with pb. (the other software are also Qt5.3.1 and x64...)

Comment: have you tried using QThread::sleep()?

Comment: I have actually commented all the Sleeps call. But the software is still crashing... I think there other function that this pc don't like. I just can't find what it does not like :(
Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finaly I gave up looking for the reason of the pb and I have reinstall windows on that pc...
Thanks for your help!